# Fixed points of complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^n$

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, projective-space

Consider the componentwise complex conjugation $\tau': \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$.

I have to show that this map "induces" a map $\tau$ on the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$ (and furthermore that the set of fixed points of $\tau$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^n$, but at the moment I only care about the first point).

I interpret "inducing" in the sense that I have to show that $\tau'$ is constant on equivalence classes. However trying to do this I get $\tau'(\lambda c) = \overline{\lambda} \tau'(c) (\neq \tau'(c)$ in general), where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and $c \in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$.

Where is the mistake in my thoughts?

Comment: If it was constant on equivalence classes, that would induce a map $\Bbb{CP}^n \to \Bbb C^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, which is certainly not true. You're supposed to show that it sends equivalence classes to equivalence classes.

Comment: That's senseful, thank you.